# Amazon Home Page automation

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium2

I am trying an automation script with amazon and trying to select the category drop-down on the home page of amazon, but unable to do.

I am providing the code below.

```
WebElement Catagory = driver.findElement(By.id("searchDropdownBox"));
Select DropDown = new Select(Catagory);
DropDown.selectByVisibleText("Electronics");
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem most probably is because no option text is visible by default.

[image]

You can either click on the dropdown (plus waiting for the bar appearance of course) or select by value:

```
DropDown.selectByValue("search-alias=electronics-intl-ship");
```

[image]

Comment: Hey  Thanks for the help. As suggested i have made changed in my code and now getting this error "ElementNotInteractableException" .providing the piece of modiefied code WebElement Catagory = driver.findElement(By.id("searchDropdownBox"));
        Select DropDown =new Select(Catagory);
        DropDown.selectByValue("search-alias=electronics");
        driver.quit(); It woukld be great if you can help me with this. I am new to selenium

Comment: Try clicking in the select before creating the DropDown object, obviously waiting for its opening after clicking.

Comment: Helloi have tried that also but nothing happenedWebElement Catagory = driver.findElement(By.id("searchDropdownBox"));
        Catagory.click();
        Select DropDown =new Select(Catagory);
        DropDown.selectByValue("search-alias=electronics");